# String from BufferedReader not splitting?

Tags: java, string, bufferedreader, bukkit

Right now I'm programming a little chat history plugin for a game, in which I want to save all messages and the time it was sent in a file, which is working perfectly, but when reading it I'm getting a little problem.
**variables:**
`history = new HashMap<Date, String>();`
This is how I load the messages:

```
public static void load(){
    File f = new File(config.getString("file"));
    if (!f.exists()){
        try {
            f.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    try{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine())!=null){
            String date = line.split(" ")[0];
            for (int i = 0; i < line.split(" ").length; i++){
                System.out.print(i+"="+line.split(" ")[i]+" ");
            }
            if (date.split(",")[0].split(".").length == 0) continue;
            line = line.replaceAll(date+" ", "");
            history.put(fromString(date), line);
        }
        br.close();
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is what I have written in the file:

```
09.01.17,18:45:26 §6[RoflFrankoc] §cHi
09.01.17,18:45:30 §6[RoflFrankoc] §cHello world
```

Now my problem:
The line `if (date.split(",")[0].split(".").length == 0) continue;` is stopping the lines from getting added to `history`. Without it I get an ArrayOutOfBoundsError: 0.
with these lines

```
for (int i = 0; i < line.split(" ").length; i++){
    System.out.print(i+"="+line.split(" ")[i]+" ");
}
```

I'm checking if it's reading correctly, which yes it is, output:

```
0=09.01.17,18:45:30
1=§6[RoflFrankoc]
2=§cHello
3=world
0=09.01.17,18:45:26
1=§6[RoflFrankoc]
2=§cHi
```

(The §c's and §6's are color codes in the API, I'm using the SpigotAPI for Minecraft)

Comment: `createNewFile()` is pointless. Just catch the `FileNotFoundException`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The character `.` is a **special character**, if you want to split your `String` using a dot as separator, you need to escape it with 2 backslashes as next:

```
if (date.split(",")[0].split("\\.").length == 0) continue;
```

Indeed keep in mind that the method [`split(String regex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) expects a [**regular expression**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) as argument.